# Will a TIP42 suffice for this project that calls for a BC559 (transistors)?

Tags: transistors

Im building a Nintendo 64 USB adapter as outlined in [this](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/Adapting-a-Nintendo-64-Joystick-to-a-PC/80) guide. For the transistor, it calls for a [BC559](http://www.hestore.hu/files/bc559c.pdf). At RadioShack, the most similar one I could find was a [TIP42](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2062613). Will this work for this particular project? I thought I was mainly looking for something with an emitter-base-voltage of 5V, which the TIP42 has. The power-dissipation collector-emitter-viltage and the collector-base-voltage are all higher on the TIP42 (or at least it looks so), but I thought those were more "maximum" sort of things.

If you haven't noticed, I'm new to all this. This is my first electronics project and I'm a bit clueless, but I learn by doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. TIP42 is a power transistor. It might do the job, but I think h(FE) is just too low and it is way too expensive. You want a general purpose PNP transistor like BC556, BC557, BC558, BC327, BC328, ...

Important parameters are:

- power dissipation;
- collector current;
- current gain (hFE)
- collector emitter voltage;

Comment: Well, I already bought it, it was $2 anyway. Is it alright if I go ahead and use this though? I may end up running back to RadioShack for something else, but I can't find either of the two you mentioned on the site either.

Comment: Ok, but the question was _if it can do the job_ and not if it's too expensive..

Comment: @m.Alin, are you responding to him? Yes, my question was whether or not this part would work.

Comment: @MarkLyons Yes, I'm responding to jippie's initial answer.

Comment: If it works you're in luck, but I'd replace it with a BC... anyway. The combination 4006 with such low current gain transistor is just not feeling right.

Comment: -1: the answer is yes. HFE will be lower but still sufficient. And the higher price is not a reason why it won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it will work. *jippie* already listed a few transistor parameters, and \$H_{FE}\$ is usually the first one I look at. That's the current gain. The BC559 is a general purpose transistor, and without checking the datasheet I know that they're at least 100 minimum.

The TIP42 is a power transistor, and they have a lot lower \$H_{FE}\$, often between 20 and 40. Datasheet says 30 at 300 mA, probably a bit higher at lower current.

Then we have to look at the base current. And what I see is Bad. The 4006 controls the base without series resistor to control the current, so that it's the 4006's internal resistance which has to do the job. Never do this, always place a series resistor. Anyway, the 4006 datasheet says it can sink 1 mA, then at an \$H_{FE}\$ of 30 the TIP42 will have a colector current up to 30 mA. Since this comes from a joystick connector that will be signal levels, and thus probably OK.

Note:
If the guys at RadioShack advised you on this they did a bad job. If you want to replace a PNP signal transistor you pick another PNP signal transistor, not a PNP power transistor. From the [stories I hear](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35318/replacements-for-a-4006-ic) Radio Shack must have the worst support you can find. (If you don't know the difference between a shift register and an opamp you shouldn't be allowed access to an electronics shop, let alone work there.) *jippie* listed a few alternatives, and Digikey offers excellent selection tools. Looking for a PNP with \$H_{FE}\$ of minimum 100 returns more than 1000 transistors.