# Replacements for a 4006 IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit, components

Im building a Nintendo 64 to PC adapter as outlined in [this](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/Adapting-a-Nintendo-64-Joystick-to-a-PC/80) guide. It calls for two [4006 ICs](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4006b.pdf). RadioShack did not have this type, but I was told the following two would work: [LM339](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2062593) or a [LM324](https://www.national.com/ds/LM/LM124.pdf). Will either of those suffice for the project mentioned above?

Comment: It's interesting that the shift registers seem to be used only to provide a delay of some sort (36 clock cycles, if I'm right). It would definitely be possible to replace the 4006 with some other type of serial in, serial out shift register wired to provide needed delay.

Comment: Is that anything I can find at RadioShack? Pretty much the extent of electronics stores near me it seems.

Comment: Also from where did you get the `USB adapter` part? The link shows a N64 to parallel port adapter. It most likely will not work with USB to parallel pot adapters.

Comment: Yes, typo. Sorry about that.

Comment: Do you have a link to a catalog of theirs? I can take a look, but I can't promise any results.

Comment: Just RadioShack.com and I can check if my store has it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the limited amount of shift registers they do have are all marked `web-only`. Out of them, you might be able to build something using an array of 4094 registers (they are 8 stage, so you'd need 5 of them), but they transition on the positive clock edge, while you need negative clock edge transition. That is solvable too, but I can't think of anything at the moment. Also those prices are horrible. Here 4096 costs about $0.25.

Comment: The only thing I think that Radio Shack has that has the potential of doing what you want (not necessarily with minimum effort) would be something like the Arduino board (and yes, I know it is overkill and overpriced for the task)

Comment: Find a list of options on [Ciiva](http://ciiva.com/CloudSearch/SearchComponent?searchCondition=CD4006)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't listen to these RadioShack guys, giving such advise is a shame to the shop!

The alternative devices you mention are entirely different. The 4000-series are digital devices and 4006 specifically is a digital shift register, both LM's are analog devices called comparator and opamp repectively. These 4006 chips are pretty standard and shouldn't be too hard to find in a decent electronics shop.

Comment: Is there anything that will work that I will be able to find at RadioShack? If you can point me to something I can locate on their site to check if it is in stock at my local store that would be great. I don't know where else I could go to find parts.

Comment: I think your problem is in that last sentence (no offense): "I don't know where else I could go to find parts.". Find another shop, one that is specialized in electronics. Ask the local TV-repair shop if they know any good shops or webshops in your neighborhood.

Comment: @jippie: note that the LM339 is a quad comparator, the LM324 is a quad *opamp*.

Comment: updated my answer @WoutervanOoijen

Answer (score 4):

**Replacement part:**

As Jippie says - the IC is completely different from what RadioShack said. I can understand advice from such shops being 'less than good' on occasion but in this case they are utterly and completely wrong - there is no comparison whatsoever in the functions of the ICs suggested as replacements.

This is an unusual IC and finding an alternative is unlikely. I have not looked to see what else is available but it may be  unique.

If essential the same functionality could be achieved with other shift register ICs.
 eg [74HC4094](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT4094.pdf) 8 stage. This has the advantage of having all outputs available (unlike the 4006) but in one block (4006 has 4 blocks) so 2 or 3 of these would do what is needed with some redesign. They are also much more widely available and also cheaper (about 60 cents in 1's at Digikey).

---

**Availability**

The CD4006 is now quite rare.

Here is the [Findchips listing for CD4006](http://www.findchips.com/avail?part=cd4006). They show Arrow, Avenet, Quest all showing stock and 1 off pricing and Nasco with stock but no price shown.

If you are in the US you can find it at [Quest in California](http://www.questcomp.com/questdetails.aspx?pn=CD4006BCN&utm_source=Findchips&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=CD4006BCN&utm_content=StandardPricing&utm_campaign=FindchipsWS) who may sell in 1's, 
They have several prices - the cheaper one looks OK.

[Avnet also show stock and 1 off pricing](http://avnetexpress.avnet.com/store/em/EMController/_/A-1083791/An-0?action=part&catalogId=500201&langId=-1&storeId=500201&CMP=KNC-Supplyframe_VSE-T11)

[Arrow. 3 in stock?](http://components.arrow.com/part/link/na/en/CD4006BF3A/Texas%20Instruments?WT.mc_id=FindChips)

---

**Circuit**

You are probably aware that this uses a PC parallel port to connect to a PC. These are 'rather rare' on new PCs. A USB to parallel port interface may or may not work.

Aspects of the circuit appear marginal - if it works it works - it may be worth looking for other user comments on it.

All diodes except the 3 right most ones pick up +5V from the port and feed it to the Nintendo as 5V supply.

N64 data on pin 2 (not touching ground despite appearances) is taken via R3 to 4006 left pin 1 = shift register input. R3 C1 form a data filter. I am not familiar wit te C64 interface but it seems that clock pulses are also fed via C64-pin 2 using DB25-3 via R1 as clock source. The shift registers in the 2 CD4006's are connected in a long chain exiting at 4006-right pin 9. The way of driving the BC559 is 'marginal" but if it works it works. Placing a 10k resistor from 4006-righht pin 9 to T1-base may make the 4006 happier. DB25-10 is the data output to the PC. It has no pullup and is relying on the port pin floating high when not driven. A 1k to 10k resistor from DB25-10 to say R4 left hand end or some other DB25 pin which is always driven to +5 V may help. But, it may work OK as is.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a Russian clone for it К176ИР10 (K176IR10). Still lot of them here in Russia and ebay also sells them: [ebay](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=%D0%9A176%D0%98%D0%A010&_sacat=0)

Comment: Here is the table of the original CD40xx chips and their clones produced in the USSR: http://zpostbox.ru/ussr_analogs_of_cmos_ic.html